# Using more measurements of lower quality or just the one with the best quality?

Tags: correlation, mean, measurement

I am currently trying to analyze some pupillometry data. The device I use gives me X and Y measurements of the pupil area (from which I compute the total area via $A = \pi \times \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2$ ).

The X-Y plot of my data looks like this:

[image]

In gray you can see my raw data points. As you see, though this effect does not seem to strongly affect participant means, there is a slight deviation from the regression line in the upper right quadrant of the figure.

**My question is**: in such a situation, would $d=X$ or $d=\frac{X+Y}{2}$ give me a more reliable measurement?

Comment: What are the parameters of the regression line?  It surely looks to me like $\hat{\beta}_1 < 1$.  Does a confidence interval on the slope include 1?  The point cloud doesn't look an ellipse, either. The two variables are pretty highly correlated, so it's likely that their mean will not be substantially more accurate than either alone.  Finally, what is your basis for concluding that measurements on the $X$ axis are "better" than measurements on the $Y$ axis?

Comment: I do not know exactly what "beta one with a hat" (sorry) means. My regression line is $y = 1.1x − 8.4$, Pearson's r is $9.7 × 10^{-1}$, and p for non-correlation is (amazingly) 0, if that helps. The reason for that assumption is the prior and non-quantified observation that people get tired in the scanner and occasionally close their eyelids just a bit, blocking measurement of the top part of the pupil, thus a lower Y but constant X.

Comment: $\hat{\beta}_1$ is the estimated regression slope.  What does a confidence interval on the slope show?  Does it include 1?  Under the assumption $\sigma^2_X = \sigma^2_Y=\sigma^2$, the variance of $\frac{X+Y}{2}$ is about $0.98\sigma^2$.  There is enough goofiness in the plot (e.g., the bifurcation in $Y$ measurement at $X \approx 55$) that I'd say using $Y$ buys more heartache than improvement.

Comment: how would I get the confidence interval of the slope? A Python or R function would be helpful - I am using [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) for my linear regressor.

Comment: summary( ) on an R lm-object returns (among other things) estimates and their standard errors for the model parameters.  These can be accessed by summary.lm(*object*)$coefficients, a *p* by 4 matrix.  Rows are the variables (named) and columns are the estimate, standard error, t-statistic, (two-tailed) observed significance level.  You can extract that object and the residual df (*lm-object* $df.residual).  Then ests <- summary.lm(*object*)$coefficients[*x*,1:2]; ff <- qt(0.975,*object* $df.residual); c(ests[1]-ff*ests[2], ests[1]+ff*[ests2]) returns lower and upper 95% confidence limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty well known that 
$$\mathrm{Var}(X+Y) = \mathrm{Var}(X) + \mathrm{Var}(Y) + 2 \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$$
or in terms of $\rho$, $\sigma^2_X$ and $\sigma^2_Y$
$$\sigma^2_{X+Y} = \sigma^2_X + \sigma^2_Y + 2\, \rho_{X,Y}\sigma_X\sigma_Y$$

I'm going to assume that the $X$ and $Y$ variance are the same, call it $\sigma^2$.  Also, your best guess at $\rho$ is $r = 0.97$.  Plug those things into the above, and you find
$$\sigma^2_{X+Y} = 3.94\,\sigma. $$
If $X$ and $Y$ were statistically independent, $\sigma^2_{X+Y}= 2\,\sigma^2$.
But you don't want the sum, you want the mean and dividing $X+Y$ by 2 reduces the variance by $\frac{1}{2^2}=\frac{1}{4}$.  So, the mean has a variance of about $0.98\,\sigma$.

In other words, the mean is very slightly better, but it's not clear to me that it is better enough to worth the trouble.  This is especially true given your participant exhaustion concern.